# Why are objects I moved into collections appearing as faint objects in the Outliner?

Tags: outliner

[image]

These faint objects were originally here but I made some collections for classification and then moved them to proper collections respectively.

I don't understand why these faint lists of objects still remain here although they have gone to other collections.

What do these mean and how can I remove them?

And I wonder whether removing them would make unsuspected problem.